# how to not count ongoing notification as app's badge count?

Tags: android, notifications

i have onGoing Notification notified by foregroundService. i wanna not count this notification for app badge count, i can't find the way to achieve it...
i create a notificationchannel like this,

```
 fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, _NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val nm = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager
        nm.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
```

and create notification,

```
fun createNotification(context: Context, remoteViews: RemoteViews) =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("notification").setContentText("notification").setOngoing(true).setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()).setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews).setContentIntent(getClickPendingIntent(context))
```

how to not count this notification in my app's badge? thanks you for your commnet in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`setShowBadge(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setShowBadge(boolean)) method on `NotificationChannel` is for:

> Sets whether notifications posted to this channel can appear as application icon badges in a Launcher. Only modifiable before the channel is submitted to `createNotificationChannel`.

So your channel creation should be using that method:

```
val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, _NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

// Add this line
channel.setShowBadge(false)

val nm = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager
nm.createNotificationChannel(channel)
```